# Parent proccess "listening" to child's messages

Tags: c++, c, parent-child, ipc

I am trying to create a program that captures certain packets and analyzes them. I use `pcap_loop` to capture the packets, which means that my program is stuck on this command indefinitely. So my solution is to create 2 proccesses, one of which will capture the packets (child) and the other one will use the extracted information to make an analysis (parent). As the program runs indefinitely and analysis happens in real time, I would like for the program to look something like this:

Child:

```
capture_packets(packet_foo());

packet_foo() {
    extract_info();
    send_to_parent()
}
```

Parent:

```
while(1) {
    wait_for_msg_from_child();
    recv_msg();
    analyze();
    printf();
}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. Is it possible to create this kind of communication? is there a better way to do this that I couldn't think of?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course is it possible for two processes to communicate, especially if there's only a single direction. You could even go so far, design a simple text protocol, and have the two talk over a pipe, e.g. `child | parent` or `capture_packets | analyzer`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's definitely possible, but I'm more interested in the part where parent "waits" for the child to send a message

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using c++, however I am mostly using C style programming as I'm not very experienced with it

Comment: With a pipe, the parent will just block until there's something to read. So the waiting comes for "free".

Comment: Oh so if parent uses read(), it will simply wait until some message comes his way? What about the other way when parent isn't currently reading and child sends multiple messages, will the messages queve up?

Comment: the messages to the parent will 'queue up' until the fifo/pipe is full (about 64k bytes) the the write to the fifo/pipe will block until the parent reads a message.  I.E. if the parent cannot keep up with the child, then child will soon be blocked (and missing incoming messages)

Comment: What would be the point of reading and writing data down a pipe, reducing your bandwidth and making life awkward? Why not put the data in shared memory, with alternating buffers maybe, and do the synchronisation via condition variables/semaphores. Faster and simpler.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It may be faster, but I think setting up alternating shared memory buffers and doing synchronisation, so everything runs smoothly is more complex than reading from a pipe. Even when you consider reading partial messages.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I will go with pipes because it seems pretty simple to implement. Analyzer getting overwhelmed shouldn't be a problem because I'm capturing only a few packets (DHCP communication).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you could use a container , in your case a queue

[std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/)

What you could do with it is a producer / consumer pattern.

The parent start the child thread , which is going to watch for any informations and send them to the parent. but how ?

By placing them on the queue , the order get's preserved (FIFO) and on the parent side , you would need to check if some informations are present in the queue. if not you don't have anything to do. But if there are some , you take them one by one and you handle them.

Be aware that std::queue is not thread safe , so you either write your own implementation that is thread safe or you protect the access to the std::queue by a mutex shared between the parent and the child(s)